# data sorting in firebase

Tags: database, firebase

I am storing a `score` for each user of my application in firebase.

```
user {
       name;
       score;
 }
```

I want to show a leaderboard with the names and scores of the top 10 users (and keep it updated in real time).
What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Did you consider using priorities to somehow encode the score? https://www.firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html

Comment: See this link: [firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html](http://firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the leaderboard example for a way to do this: https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#example/leaderboard

The basic principle is that in addition to setting the name and score in a user object, you can use `setWithPriority` to also set a priority for it. Priority in this particular case can be the user's score (if its numeric, it will automatically be sorted for you). You can then use the `.limit(10)` query to get a list of top 10 users.

You'll also have to implement the `child_added`, `child_changed` and `child_removed` events to handle the cases of a new user entering the top 10, someone changing position and someone leaving the top 10 list respectively.

Comment: If you have existing records that were inserted without using setWithPriority, how would you either a) retrofit them, or b) sort them without that being set?