# Firebase retrieve highest 100 score

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is a screen shot of my firebase:
[image]
I am trying to retrieve the highest 100 score in firebase database 
I am using this code to add new node to firebase:

```
 Map<String, String> post1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        post1.put("name",name);
        post1.put("score",score);
        myRef.push().setValue(post1);
```

And this is the code I am using to retrieve the highest 100 score which doesn't work (the code works but it is not retrieving the highest 100 score)

```
 Query queryRef = myRef.orderByChild("score").limitToFirst(100);
        queryRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Score score=postSnapshot.getValue(Score.class);
                    Log.d("test"," values is " + score.getName()  + " " + score.getScore());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: It's better to store scores as number instead of strings. Check out the comments on frank's answer for more info.

Answer (score 8):

Firebase queries are always in ascending order. So you'll need to get the **last** 100, instead of the first 100.

```
Query queryRef = myRef.orderByChild("score").limitToLast(100);
```

Then client-side you'll need to reverse the items.

Alternatively you can add a inverted property to your items `invertedScore: -99`. If you do that, you can order by that inverted score and won't have to reverse the array.

This scenario has been covered frequently before. I highly recommend you study some of these:

- [data sorting in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19278116/data-sorting-in-firebase/19278582#19278582)
- [Firebase Leaderboard, best Implmentation. SQL Joins and orderby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39449507/firebase-leaderboard-best-implmentation-sql-joins-and-orderby/39453272#39453272) (as recently as yesterday)
- [Display posts in descending posted order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25611356/display-posts-in-descending-posted-order/25613337#25613337)
- [Firebase Data Desc Sorting in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156996/firebase-data-desc-sorting-in-android/34158197#34158197)
- [Swift - How to create Sort query as Descending on Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314374/swift-how-to-create-sort-query-as-descending-on-firebase)

Comment: I'm wondering if this will actually work because in the question the scores are strings and not numbers. Won't it sort something like this: "1", "12", "2", "3", "33", "333", "4"?

Comment: Darn.... good catch André. Apparently I have a blind spot, because I swear I checked whether they were stored as number. **The above will indeed only work if you store the scores as number (or as zero-padded strings)**.

Answer (score 0):

this is a way to fetch highest salary from firebas
or get highest number from firebase

```
one   citiesRef.orderBy("name").limit(3);
two   citiesRef.orderBy("name", "desc").limit(3);
three citiesRef.where("population", ">", 100000).orderBy("population").limit(2);
four  citiesRef.where("population", ">", 100000).orderBy("population");
```